# Prevent RD users from storing password in WebAccess (RdWeb)?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

When my users opens RdWeb (eg. from home) and enter their credentials, then they are presented with this dialog...

[image]

How can I prevent them from storing their password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a client side feature and cannot reliably be disabled from the server side.

There is a way to "suggest" to the browser that it should not be saved, but this is not a standard:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="login.cgi" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality) for more information

If you have control over the client computers, then of course you can disable the feature client-side for IE by GPO:

```
[Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Network access: Do not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports for network authentication]
```